# jQuery image uploader with localStorage. Partially working. Default image not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am working on a admin feature for company control panel. The widget I am trying to create is for admin's to replace the default logo on the control panel with their own company logo.

I'm using localStorage for proof of concept but it will be saved into database and CMS at production.

I have the basics working in terms of uploading a new image/logo and replacing the default. However, we are pre-seeding the control panel header with an "out of box" default logo. For some reason, the default logo does not show up when page is first loaded. You currently get a broken image icon. Once you upload a new image it replaces the header logo and keeps the current selection in the admin widget.

If you refresh page it recalls this from localStorage which is working just fine but if you reset, you will notice that the pre-seeded logo does not appear.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = localStorage.theImage;

$('.logoArea').html(img);
$("body").on("change", ".uploadLogo", function() {
    var fileInput = $(this)[0];
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // CREATE A NEW IMAGE
        var img = new Image();

        img.src = reader.result;
        localStorage.theImage = reader.result; // STORE IMAGE IN LOCAL STORAGE
        $(".logoArea").html(img);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Please see fiddle for working model

> **Update:** This was resolved and I updated fiddle below to working version in case it helps anyone else out.

https://jsfiddle.net/evmcatj1/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first Load the `localStorage.theImage;` is `undefined` you should use a default image in case is the first time that the user opens the page

Comment: Thanks for the direction Matho. This issue is resolved.